# How to display the other images along with popped up image?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I want to achieve the images as pop-up and also other images along with pop-up.

I have used the *color box* module for displaying the images as pop up.

Now, I displayed the image in pop up but i couldnt get the others images with that pop up

[image]

Like this, I want to display the other images as thumbnail under the popped up image.

And when the thumbnail image is checked, popping up image should be hidden and the thumbnail image should be shown.

Please guide me, how to do this one ?

NOTE: I have used the *Test content* in articles content type, and added the unlimited images in image fields. And passed the content ID in contextual filter to display the images.

Comment: Please clear you want to  show thumbnail images and base image both on the screen.

Comment: Please have a look in above image. I want to do exactly the same like above image

Comment: yes, i understand i just know , you want when you click on the thumbnail then display image is hide and clicked image is show as popup. Right?

Comment: Yeah exactly. The popped up image should be hidden and thumbnail should be shown, when the thumbnail image is checked

Comment: you can check lightbox 2 module.

Comment: @Smalution I will check